# Wpf Listview header Margin set to 0

Tags: wpf, listview

How can I set listview header margin to 0 ? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the Margin of the entire `ListView` Control. Try setting the Header Margin to `-3,-3,-3,0`.

Comment: No not for entire ListView. question is where to set Header Margin?

Comment: Just access the `HeaderStyle` Property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.listview.headerstyle.aspx

Comment: Thanks for answer , but ListView.HeaderStyle is for windows forms, i need for wpf.

Comment: Well you are right, Im sorry. Please refer to this Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms788747.aspx
Using this Template you can overwrite the default Template and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: <Style x:Key="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}"
       TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader">
  <Setter Property= .....  here ?  I set, but nothing happens :(

Comment: Please download this example: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7741

Comment: Thank You!But in this exaple there is exists this issue ,see attached image please (i update question)

Comment: Thank you, example you sent, helped me.

Comment: Hey, no problem. Please don't forget to vote if you found my answer helpful.